# How to view the contents of a file in python

Tags: python, function, if-statement, authentication, view

I am trying to add a new account in my file which already consist of a username and password of other accounts,  after doing it I only want to view the new added accounts or contents of the file like this but have certain distances with each other:

No.   Account Name      Username             Password

1       Facebook                    admin                123admin

2       Google                        user                 123user

Below is my code for adding a new account in my file:

```
def Add_account():

    account = input("\nEnter the name of the account: ")
    username = input(f"Enter the username of your {account}: ")
    password = input(f"Enter the password of your {account}: ")
    ask = input(f"Do you want to save {account} credentials? [Y|N]: ")

    if new_ask == "Y":
        with open("info.txt", "a") as file:
            file.write("\n" + encrypt(account) + ":" + encrypt(username) + ":" + encrypt(password))
            file.close()
         
Add_account()
```

How can I view the new accounts only in my file?

Comment: where and how do you want to view them?

Comment: I want to view it in the terminal of my program.

Comment: I want to add a new method but I don't know where to start.

Comment: append the data you write to the file to some list, then just print that list

Comment: Can you please show me an example code? I'm really new this.

Comment: just create a list and append the same thing you write to the file to that list, then when needed print out the contents of that list, those are python basics and if you know how to write to files you should know how to append to a list too